# Visual Studio Code doesn't run the Django site

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code

I'm learning Django with Visual Studio Code.

When I start the site by `python manage.py runserver` it doesn't start, but in [Command Prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJHQD.png) it works. How can I get it to work within Visual Studio Code?

```
[18/Aug/2023 10:12:58] "GET /phones/ HTTP/1.1" 200 46
F:\tryInWeb\mysite>

F:\tryInWeb\mysite>

F:\tryInWeb\mysite>

F:\tryInWeb\mysite>

F:\tryInWeb\mysite>python manage.py runserver 
Watching for file changes with StatReloader 
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

You have 18 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app(s): admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions. 
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.
August 18, 2023 - 10:15:22
Django version 4.2.1, using settings 'mysite.settings' 
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.

[18/Aug/2023 10:15:25] "GET /phones/categories HTTP/1.1" 301 0 
[18/Aug/2023 10:15:25] "GET /phones/categories/ HTTP/1.1" 200 50

F:\tryInWeb\mysite>
```

[image]

Comment: Do not post images of errors or codes. It's best to copy them here and use Stack overflow's formatting tools for improved readability.

Comment: VSCode is just a lightweight editor, and the terminal is consistent with the system shell. You can try replacing powershell with CMD. If it doesn't work, please check your python interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough detail but seems like PowerShell might have these tow problems:

- different python is using
- the virtual environment is not added or used

if you want to run a **Django** project you definitely must use the [virtual environment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/development_environment) for it. unless the Python packages that you installed using pip might interrupt the Django packages.
the fastest way to solve your problem is simply to press this button near the plus sign:

[image]

and then use command prompt instead of powershell :

[image]